# Escape de regex no php

Tags: php, regex

local-config_form_settings-**teste**
Para dar match no "teste", estou utilizando esta regex:

```
(?<=config_form_settings-)([a-z0-9]+)
```

Testei a regex aqui: https://regex101.com/ e está do jeito que eu quero.
No php estou usando o preg_quote para dar escape nos grupos de captura:

```
if (preg_match(preg_quote("(?<=peerreview_form_settings-)([a-z0-9]+)"), $result['name'], $matches) == true) {
  print("Match");
}
```

Mas deste jeito não da match em nada.
Alguem sabe qual o problema da regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (preg_match(preg_quote("(/?<=peerreview_form_settings-)([a-z0-9]+)/"), $result['name'], $matches) == true) {
  print("Match");
}
```

Faltou o indicador `/` para indicar o começo e o fim da regular expression.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, era isso mesmo

Comment: "devem"? eu uso `~`, `#`, `@`.

Comment: Corrigido, @GuilhermeLautert obrigado pela indicação.